# Adding dynamic screen overlay to a track

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to be able to place some dynamic overlays on the screen that change along with playing a track. I don't now if this is possible at all, which is why I am asking for advice.

After having recorded a track on my GPS device, I import it into Google Earth as a track, which I can then play back. What I wish to do then is to make a screen overlay that displays the speed, altitude, heartrate, temperature etc. as I play back the track.

I am able to analyse the GPX (or KML) file myself, and calculate the necessary data at each point on the track, so I am not asking for help there. What I do need help with is how to get this data combined with a track in the KML file.

Imagine that I have a track with 500 points, and then 500 overlay images, which I have gererated on the side. How do I get the system to dynamically flip through the overlay images as I play the track? I would like one overlay image to be associated with one point on the track, preferably in a way that makes it possible to scroll back and forth in the track, by using the build in functions in Google Earth, and then have the overlay images follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I made a separate program to generate and show the overlays, which I syncronize with Google Earth, and that works just fine.